# JQGrid - rowdata columname case sensitive

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using rowdata to get all values from JQgrid. Below is my code.

```
OnDblClickRow : 
var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId);
```

sometimes before it works with `rowData.EntryUserMasterId`, now it is giving value only by when using `rowData.ENTRYUSERMASTERID`.

Inside grid columnname is `EntryUserMasterId`, then why and how it takes capital in `rowData`.

How can i use ignorecase in rowdata columnnames?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you post seems not like JavaScript code, but jqGrid is full written in JavaScript. The properties of the object returned by `getRowData` are **the same** as the values of `name` properties in `colModel`. If it returns `EntryUserMasterId` then you have the column with `name: "EntryUserMasterId"`. In any way if you report a problem, then you should *always* write, which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

JavaScript is **case sensitive**. There are no option to inform to use `rowData.EntryUserMasterId` and `rowData.ENTRYUSERMASTERID` as **the same**. Thus you should use the names of the properties like in `colModel`. The only thing what you can do, if you don't now exactly the `colModel`, is the following. You can enumerate the properties of `rowData` object returned by `getRowData` using

```
var prop;
for (propin rowData) {
    if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop.toUpperCase() === "ENTRYUSERMASTERID") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, but by using this i can't say my prop is in uppercase or lowercase, if it is in lower then it won't give value. so, i need to compare prop with upper and lower both. Actually, title prop in column of jqgrid is what it shows in grid header UI (title = "EntryUserMasterId"). and id is different(gridname_ENTRYUSERMASTERID), so it won't give value.

Comment: @Priya: You are welcome! You don't post any code. Because of that it's difficult for me to gives you any tips. I suppose that you make some simple errors, which can be easy solved, but I can't help you if I don't see the code. The `title` is **not the same** as column name. One can use both `colModel` and `colNames` and one can specify in `colModel` 3 properties, which will be frequently mixed: `name`, `label` and `index.` I suppose that you try to use labels (colNames) instead of column names.

Comment: @Priya: In any way the code, which I posted have to work. If you compare two strings saved in variables (not constant string with the upper case value `"ENTRYUSERMASTERID"`) then you should convert **both** operands to upper case (like `prop.toUpperCase() === testProp.toUpperCase()`)